# Android webview, too large bundle size than I expected

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-bundle, android-savedstate

My in-app-browser's onSaveInstanceState looks like this

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putBoolean(BUNDLE_INITIAL_PAGE_LOADED, wasTheInitialPageLoaded)
    webView.saveState(outState)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

In the code, after executing webView.saveState(outState), the data size of outState goes up 4KB.
So far is okay, but, if I click some links two or three times, the data size of outState goes up to 400KB.
It looks like there is some recursive problem. Is it normal situation?

Comment: I think that it is normal due to not only your data is saved, but likely WebView internal data as well. For example goBack history, cached HTML...

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Surfing one page takes 4KB and Surfing one more page takes 400KB. It sounds not normal.
Google's recommended bundle size is under 50KB

Comment: Why don't you check which data is store d there in the `outState`?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tried it, but, I don't know what variable to read from the parcel of key "WEBVIEW_CHROMIUM_STATE". Printing all contents of parcel is really hard

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing webView.saveState(outState).
It doesn't needed at the first place.
With orientation changing, the website elements are perfectly saved and restored including edittext's string content.